# SQL Join with Multiple Rows of a Single Table + filter by another table

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask for help.

I have this 3 tables in my database:

Table 'Users':

```
|ID|   Name|   Surname| Status |
----------------------------------
|14 |    Joe|    Smith|     1  |
|15 |   Paul|   Taylor|     1  |
|16 | Martin|     List|     1  |
```

Table 'user_data':

```
|IDuser|     IDciselnik|       skUserValue|
--------------------
|14     |             1|   value1 text Joe|
|14     |             3|   value3 text Joe|
|14     |             4|                25|
|15     |             1|  value1 text Paul|
|15     |             3|  value3 text Paul|
|15     |             4|                26|
|16     |             1|value1 text Martin|
|16     |             3|value3 text Martin|
|16     |             4|                22|
```

Table 'ciselnik':

```
|ID|    skTitle|
--------------------
|25 |    Kosice|
|26 |  Skošicel|
|22 |    Prague|
```

if I want to get output like below, with all users:

Output:

```
|userID | Name    | Surname | value_ID1          | value_ID3          |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 14    |  Joe    |   Smith | value1 text Joe    | value3 text Joe    |
| 15    |  Paul   |  Taylor | value1 text Paul   | value3 text Paul   |
| 16    |  Martin |    List | value1 text Martin | value3 text Martin |
```

I know I can get with :

```
SELECT us.ID AS userID, us.Name, us.Surname, 
max(CASE WHEN ud.IDciselnik =1 THEN ud.skUserValue END) value_ID1, 
max(CASE WHEN ud.IDciselnik =3 THEN ud.skUserValue END) value_ID3
FROM user_data ud LEFT JOIN Users us ON us.ID = ud.IDuser 
WHERE us.Status=1 
GROUP BY us.ID ORDER BY value_ID3 DESC
```

But, I have search button and I want to filter only users from "kosice" or similar name.
first I need to get all ID from table 'ciselnik' where the "kosice" exist
and then the IDs from 'ciselnik' I need to check/compare which user have it, and select only the users which has skUserValue equal with 'ciselnik'

simply in my output I don't need to get all users, but as in output example:

```
|userID | Name    | Surname | value_ID1          | value_ID3          | skTitle |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 14    |  Joe    |   Smith | value1 text Joe    | value3 text Joe    | Kosice |
| 15    |  Paul   |  Taylor | value1 text Paul   | value3 text Paul   | Skošicel |
```

I used this

```
SELECT us.ID AS userID, us.Name, us.Surname, c.skTitle,  
max(CASE WHEN ud.IDciselnik =1 THEN ud.skUserValue END) value_ID1, 
max(CASE WHEN ud.IDciselnik =3 THEN ud.skUserValue END) value_ID3
FROM user_data ud LEFT JOIN Users us ON us.ID = ud.IDuser 
LEFT JOIN ciselnik c ON c.ID = ud.skUserValue 
WHERE us.Status=1 
AND c.skTitle COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE '%kosice%' 
GROUP BY us.ID ORDER BY value_ID3 DESC
```

I have now problem, that in my Output this: value_ID1 and value_ID3 are NULL
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be

```
SELECT u.Name, u.Surname, d1.skUserValue AS value_ID1, d3.skUserValue AS value_ID3
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN user_data d1 ON u.IDuser = u.ID AND d1.IDciselnik =1
LEFT JOIN user_data d3 ON u.IDuser = u.ID AND d3.IDciselnik =3
LEFT JOIN user_data d4 ON u.IDuser = u.ID AND d4.IDciselnik =4
LEFT JOIN ciselnik c ON d4.skUserValue = c.ID
WHERE c.skTitle LIKE '%blah%'
```

By joining the data table under different aliases you can filter each subset by the id in the join condition.

Comment: Left join x where x is the same as inner join x

Comment: @Alden W. - thank you a lot for the answer.
Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for.
now when I use this:

Comment: `SELECT us.ID AS userID, us.Name, us.Surname, c.skTitle, ud1.skUserValue AS value_ID1, ud3.skUserValue AS value_ID3, ud4.skUserValue AS value_ID4
    FROM Users us
    LEFT JOIN user_data ud1 ON ud1.IDuser = us.ID AND ud1.IDciselnik =1
    LEFT JOIN user_data ud3 ON ud3.IDuser = us.ID AND ud3.IDciselnik =3
    LEFT JOIN user_data ud4 ON ud4.IDuser = us.ID AND ud4.IDciselnik =4 
    LEFT JOIN ciselnik c ON ud4.skUserValue = c.ID
    WHERE us.Status=1 AND c.skTitle COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE '%kosice%' GROUP BY us.ID ORDER BY ud3.skUserValue DESC`

Output is which I need.